# Putting algebraic curves in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $X \subset \mathbb{C}^2$ be a smooth algebraic curve. Thinking of $\mathbb{C}^2$ as $\mathbb{R}^4$, is there a smooth map $\phi: \mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ so that $\phi: X \to \mathbb{R}^3$ is a closed injective immersion? I mean this question in two senses:

- Does the map $\phi$ exist at all?
- Can we actually write down some simple formula for it, in terms of coordinates $x_1+i y_1$, $x_2+i y_2$ on $\mathbb{C}^2$ and the defining equation $F(x_1+iy_1,x_2+iy_2)=0$ of $X$?

The motivation for this question is that I'd like to make some pretty pictures of algebraic curves.

Comment: Have you already tested some (nontrivial) examples?

Comment: I would suspect not, since the real dimension of $X$ is two, the secant variety fills up (it will be four dimensional in general) the Euclidean space, giving you no room to project to get an injective map. Of course, this does not mean it is impossible, but seems unlikely.

Comment: @Mohan This argument shows linear maps can't work. I agree with that, and have checked that the secant map does fill up in concrete cases. It says nothing about more interesting smooth maps.

Comment: Absolutely. Just can't think of some intrinsic nice maps other than projections.

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan I'm not sure what a serious test would mean. Here are minor things I've thought: Lines are easy. Conics are fine -- I can change coordinates to $z_1 z_2=1$ and then use $(z_1, z_2) \mapsto (\mathrm{Re}(z_1), \mathrm{Im}(z_1), |z_2|^2)$. (continued)

Comment: Mikhalkin https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0010087 shows that, if $X$ is a Harnack curve, then $(z_1, z_2) \mapsto (\mathrm{Re}(z_1), \mathrm{Re}(z_2))$ covers a closed region in $\mathbb{R}^2$, mapping $2 \to 1$ onto the interior and $1 \to 1$ onto the boundary. The preimage of the boundary is $X \cap \mathbb{R}^2$, and this disconnects $X$. So I just need to write down a function which has different signs on the two components of $X \setminus \mathbb{R}^2$ and take that as the third coordinate of the map. Abstract arguments show such a function exists, but I haven't found an explicit formula.

Comment: Not quite what you are asking,  but related questions were studied in the context of mininal surfaces. One  result says  that under certain assumptions on a region $D \subset \mathbb{R}^n, \ n \geq 3$ every bordered Riemann surface $M$ admits a continuous map  to $\overline{D}$ which is 
 is a conformal full complete proper minimal immersion on $M^\circ$, in    MR3407187 Alarc\'on, A.Drinovec Drnov\v sek, B.; Forstneri\v c, F; L\'opez, F. J.
Every bordered Riemann surface is a complete conformal minimal surface bounded by Jordan curves. 
Proc. Lond. Math. Soc. (3) 111 (2015), no. 4, 851–886

Comment: Are you interested in the case that $\phi$ is the defined just in $\mathbb{C}^2 \setminus \{ 0 \}$ ? For example, taking first a radial projection from $\mathbb{R}^4$ to $S^3 \subset \mathbb{R}^4$ then stereographic projection to some tangente space. In any case, I do not know if the pictures you get doing so are going to be pretty.

Comment: Would not the "[usual](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31904/how-to-visualize-riemann-surfaces)" way satisfy you? I mean, putting Riemann surfaces in ${\mathbb C}\times{\mathbb R}$ by, say, $(f(x+iy),|g(x+iy)|)$ where $(f,g)$ is some (local) parametrization of $X$?

Comment: @Holonomia:  For most algebraic curves $X\subset\mathbb{C}^2$, the union of the (complex) tangent lines to $X$ is all of $\mathbb{C}^2$, so radially projecting $X$ onto a $3$-sphere in $\mathbb{R}^4=\mathbb{C}^2$ will introduce some 'pinch' points in the image (generically speaking, the same number as the dual degree of the curve minus the number of points on the line at infinity).  In general, to do what David wants to do, you'd at least have to choose a smooth nonvanishing section of the normal bundle of $X$ in $\mathbb{C}^2$, which is possible (since $X$ is not compact) but not easy.

Comment: @Robert Bryant: I was aware of that. Actually, I had in mind pictures of Fermat's curves $x^n + y^n - 1 = F(x,y) $. If I made not mistakes there are not pinch points when projecting radially to $S^3$. Pinch points must satisfy the system $F(x,y)=0  ,  F_x \cdot x + F_y \cdot y = 0$.  Thus if David wants to drawn "some" pretty pictures perhaps this can be interesting for him.

Comment: @Holonomia: Yes, that's *an* example of a curve for which the $S^3$ projection doesn't have pinch points (or even self-intersections). However, such pinch points *will* exist for most algebraic curves. Also, contrary to David's requirement, the image of your curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$ won't be closed. The image of the radial projection into $S^3\subset\mathbb{C}^2$ will have $n$ great circles in its closure that don't belong to the image (corresponding to the $n$ points on the line at infinity on the original curve), and these will survive as non-closed points after you stereographically project.

Comment: So you think that David is not interested into radial + stereographic projection of the Fermat's curves, isn't it?

Comment: @Holonomia:  Whether David will be interested in this particular construction or not, I can't say.  I'll let him answer that.  I'm just pointing out that this construction won't satisfy his request that the immersion be closed.  Instead, each of the $n$ missing points on the line at infinity will show up as  circles that are boundaries of the surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that results from your construction.

Comment: @Robert Bryant:  David's picture is going to be inside some "box". So if the problem is the presence of boundary curves I think they do not disappear with technical assumtion of the immersion being closed. Thus, I am putting more stress on David's aim to draw pretty pictures than on the precise technical request. I'm misunderstanding David's motivation?

Comment: @Holonomia:  I can't answer this for David.  He'll have to do that.  I just pointed out that this construction doesn't answer David's actual question.

Answer (score 4):

Taking this as two questions, the second being more interesting than the first, I can at least answer the first (less interesting) question.  The answer is 'Yes, such maps $\phi:\mathbb{C}^2\to\mathbb{R}^3$ do exist, though they (necessarily) depend on the smooth curve $X$'.

Given a smooth algebraic curve $X\subset\mathbb{C}^2$, suppose that $X$ is defined as the zero locus of an reduced polynomial $F(z,w)$ (i.e., $F$ has no multiple factors).  Then, by the assumption that $X$ is smooth (by which I assume that David means 'smooth, embedded'), the polynomials, $F$, $F_z$ and $F_w$ have no common zeros.  In fact, for each $x\in X$, the vector $N(x)=\bigl(\,\overline{F_z(x)},\,\overline{F_w(x)}\,\bigr)$ is nonzero and (unitarily) orthogonal to the (complex) tangent line to $X$ at $x$, since the $1$-form $\mathrm{d}F = F_z\,\mathrm{d}z+F_w\,\mathrm{d}w$ vanishes when pulled back to the curve $X$.  Let $U(x)= N(x)/|N(x)|$ be the corresponding unit vector.

Now, because $X$ is smooth and algebraic, outside a compact set, it is asymptotic to a finite set of lines, and it is not difficult to see that there is a positive function $e:X\to (0,1)$ such that the mapping $S:X\times\Delta(1)\to\mathbb{C}^2$ (where $\Delta(r)\subset\mathbb{C}$ is the disk of radius $r>0$ about $0$) defined by
$$
S(x,t) = x + t\,e(x)U(x)
$$
is an injective diffeomorphism.  (If all of the asmptotic lines of $X$ are distinct, one can even take $e$ to be a (suitably small) constant.)

Now, we also know that $X$ is a compact (oriented) Riemann surface with a (nonzero) finite number of points removed. (In fact, $X$ has no compact components.) As such, there exists a smooth, closed embedding $\psi: X\to \mathbb{R}^3$ with the property that the normal 'tube' of radius $1$ around $\psi(X)$ is also smoothly embedded.  Let $u:X\to S^2$ be a unit normal vector field for the immersion $\psi$ and extend $\psi$ to $\psi:X\times [-\tfrac12,\tfrac12]\to\mathbb{R}^3$ by setting
$$
\psi(x,t) = \psi(x) + t\,u(x)
$$
for $|t|\le \tfrac12$.  Now, I claim that there is a smooth map $\phi:S\bigl(X\times \Delta(\tfrac12)\bigr)\to \mathbb{R}^3$ that satisfies
$$
\phi\bigl(S(x,t)\bigr) = \psi\bigl(x,\mathrm{Re}(t)\bigr)
$$
whenever $|t|\le\tfrac12$ and that it is a smooth submersion on an open neighborhood of $X\subset S\bigl(X\times \Delta(\tfrac12)\bigr)$ that is injective and immersive on $X$ itself.

Now, extend $\phi$ smoothly any way one likes beyond the set $S\bigl(X\times \Delta(\tfrac12)\bigr)\subset\mathbb{C}^2$. (One can even require that $\phi$ take the complement of $S\bigl(X\times \Delta(1)\bigr)$ to a single point of $\mathbb{R}^3$.)

Unfortunately, there may be no simple recipe for choosing $\psi$, which is what one would really need to get an affirmative answer to the second question.

Answer (score 1):

Henry Segerman has asked a similar [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/200172/map-of-the-klein-quartic-from-cp2-to-r3) about curves in $\mathbb{CP}^2$ and then managed to produce the [sculpture](http://gallery.bridgesmathart.org/exhibitions/2016-joint-mathematics-meetings/schleimer-segerman) (of the Klein quartic).  So perhaps he will have something interesting to say...

Comment: It might be worth pointing out, though, that, if $X\subset\mathbb{CP}^2$ is  a smooth algebraic curve, then its normal bundle is not trivial, and this implies that there cannot be a smooth map $\phi:\mathbb{CP}^2\to\mathbb{R}^3$ that is both an injective immersion when restricted to $X$ and a submersion on an open neighborhood of $X$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the surface in $\mathbb{R}^4$ with equations 
\begin{align*}
 x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2 &=1 \\
(3x_3^2-2)x_4-\sqrt{2}(x_1^2-x_2^2)x_3 &=0.
\end{align*} 
[image]

This is conformally isomorphic to the normalization of the hyperelliptic curve $$w^2=z^5-(a^2+a^{-2})z^3+z, $$ for a unique value of $a\in(0,1)$ which is approximately $0.0983562$.  It is also conformally isomorphic to the quotient of the unit disc by a certain Fuchsian group which again depends on a single parameter $b\in(0,1)$ which is approximately $0.8005319$.  There is a very long story behind all this, which is spelled out in my memoir "Uniformization of embedded surfaces" at https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.06433.  There is also a large body of associated Maple code and pictures which can be downloaded from the arxiv, or more conveniently from https://neilstrickland.github.io/genus2/.

Comment: Can you find the map $\phi$ ?